# Read logfile with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to read added text to a logfile and extract parts of that to save in a database (number > S3.20.140, start scan, scanId, scanTime, result). I need to read the following block:

```
[2015-06-23 13:45:01.768] .
[2015-06-23 13:45:01.768] Scan requested
[2015-06-23 13:45:01.768] random selection - S3.20.140 3 - 3
[2015-06-23 13:45:01.768] SV_ET_CMD_TYPE.SV_ET_CMD_SCAN: S3.20.140
[2015-06-23 13:45:01.784] Notification: Activity=SCAN_STARTED ScanId=14
[2015-06-23 13:45:07.884] SCUMsgClient: to receive 235 rectangles
[2015-06-23 13:45:07.884] Total scan 14 time: - 6.1 sec
[2015-06-23 13:45:07.915] HIP detection result is "OBJECTS DETECTED"
[2015-06-23 13:45:07.915] Scan results are ready.
[2015-06-23 13:45:11.128] User cleared scan 14
[2015-06-23 13:45:11.128] .
```

This block will be the same for every scan, but there is other information in the logfile that I do not wanna process. What will be the best approach for this?

Comment: The following probably isn't the most helpful comment, but nonetheless:  What have you already tried? And what is the problem you have encountered?

Comment: Usually, such questions come with previous attempts. Without them and clear statement what is not working it is not easy to guess what the groups are or what they may contain.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string inputLine = "";
            string pattern1 = @"^\[(?'datetime'[^\]]*)\](?'message'[^$]*)";
            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                Match match = expr.Match(inputLine);
                string x = match.Groups["datetime"].Value;
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups["datetime"].Value);
                string message = match.Groups["message"].Value;
                if (message.Contains(":"))
                {
                    string[] array = message.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    switch (array[0].Trim())
                    {
                        case "SV_ET_CMD_TYPE.SV_ET_CMD_SCAN" :
                            Console.WriteLine("Number : {0}", array[1].Trim());
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: I've been parsing files like this for over 40 years.  Regex is a very useful tool but you have to know when and where to use it.  With text data is often better to read one line at a time and parse an individual line than to use Regex to parse the entire input in one shot.  In this case the DateTime has colons and the log message has a colon.  So you need to break up the line parsing in two pieces.  The code I posted is very readable any most people can easily figure out what is occurring.  I suspect that additional filtering is going to be needed and add comments wen I update.